# Importing XML files

Tags: java, xml, xslt

How to import a XML file in other XML file?

I have 4 XML classes in a spring project and I don't want to give all the in context configuration, I just want to a single file in configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference guide suggests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import), for example:

```
<import resource="services.xml"/>
<import resource="resources/messageSource.xml"/>
<import resource="/resources/themeSource.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To import an XML document, You need to execute the LIBNAME statement for the XML engine in order to assign a brief to the physical location of an existing XML documents. Then you will be able to execute SAS code to access the XML code.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with SAS? Question does not mention it